# Yii2 AJAX form not validating

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm migrating my site from Yii to Yii2 and trying to make a basic loan calculator. was reading the documentation and some answers on stack that suggested to use `validationUrl`.

Below is my code i've done so far. but i can't get my form validation to work. It allows me to submit an empty form. and doesn't show any errors?

Also where do i put my calculations, in actionloanValidate() or actionIndex() ?

```
<?php 
                        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                            'id' => $model->formName(),
                            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                            'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(['calculator/default/loan-validate'])
                        ]);
                    ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'price') ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'downpayment') ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'rate') ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model,'yearloan')->dropDownList(
                                ['1' => '1 (12 months)', '2' => '2 (24 months)'); 
                    ?>

                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block', 'tabindex' => '3']) ?>

                    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () { 
                        var $form = $("#<?= $model->formName() ?>");
                        $form.on("beforeSubmit", function (event, messages) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $.ajax({
                                "type":"POST",
                                "url":$form.attr('action'),
                                "data":$form.serialize(),
                                "beforeSend":function( xhr ) {},
                                "dataType":"json",
                                "cache": true, 
                                "success":function(data){
                                    $("#totalLoanAmount").html(data.totalLoanAmount);
                                    $("#monthlyInstallment").html(data.monthlyInstallment);
                                    $("#loanCalcTable").html(data.loanCalcTable);   
                                },                                        
                            });
                            return false;       
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
```

in my controller i have this

```
        public function actionIndex() {
    $model=new calculatorForm;
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            //DO CALCULATION HERE!!
        } 
        return $this->render('loan-calculator', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
        }

public function actionloanValidate()
        {
            $model=new calculatorForm;
            
            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validate($model);
            }
    
            else {
                return $this->renderAjax('loan-calculator', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
                
        }
```

my model rules are

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            //loan-calculator validation 
            [['price', 'downpayment', 'rate', 'yearloan'], 'required']
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need AJAX validation? `required` works directly on the client side, ActiveForm won't allow the form to be submitted until all the required fields have data on them.

Comment: @RaulSauco iwa nt to do the calculations in the backend. and return a json to to populate a few ID's on the page. i don't want the page to refresh when the form is submitted. how would i do this?

Comment: If you consider the operation that is taking place **validation** then you probably want to have a look at implementing your own [deferred validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#deferred-validation). But it does not look like you are doing any validation, based on your code, and your comment, it looks like you just want to send a few values to the server and get some values back, asynchronously, it isn't very clear what that has to do with Yii validaton.

Comment: It looks like you just need an `actionCalculateLoan()` that takes in some inputs and returns the calculated data as JSON, have your JavaScript call that function, and process the results when you receive them. You probably also want to display some kind of loading indicator while you are waiting for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the validation check by defining `beforeSubmit` in your javascript.  You are also likely getting a cancelled ajax request as you need to call `event.stopPropagation()` after `event.preventDefault()`

If you are truly trying to achieve only required validation, don't use ajaxValidation.

On beforeSubmit validate the form

```
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation(); //stops going to submit which will cancel your ajax
    //a trick added to ensure validation is triggered on untouched fields
    data = $form.data("yiiActiveForm");
        $.each(data.attributes, function() {
            this.status = 3;
        });

    $form.yiiActiveForm("validate");

    if ($("#form").find(".has-error").length) {
        return false;
    }
                            $.ajax({
                                "type":"POST",
                                "url":$form.attr('action'),
                                "data":$form.serialize(),
                                "beforeSend":function( xhr ) {},
                                "dataType":"json",
                                "cache": true, 
                                "success":function(data){
                                    $("#totalLoanAmount").html(data.totalLoanAmount);
                                    $("#monthlyInstallment").html(data.monthlyInstallment);
                                    $("#loanCalcTable").html(data.loanCalcTable);   
                                },                                        
                            });
```

As well, the calculcation should be done in the `actionIndex` (the action of the form)